# Is there any mathematically rigorous definition of deriving a matrix valued function with respect to one of its matrix argument?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

On my way of satudying Heisenberg matrix mechanics, I get blocked by formulas engaging derivations with respect to a matrix arguments. My question is the following : Is there any mathematically rigorous definition of deriving a matrix-valued function with respect to one of its matrix argument ? thanks in advance.

Comment: The entries of an $m\times n$ matrix give you (without further restrictions) $mn$ independent variables, and a function of the matrix is in turn a function of those $mn$ variables. Take partial derivatives as you ordinarily would.

Comment: You can consider the Frechet derivative or Gateaux derivatives. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative In finite-dimensional spaces, the Gateaux derivative is equivalent to using partial derivatives.

Comment: As others have said, a matrix can be viewed as a vector, so you can take partial derivatives. But I prefer to use the concept of a directional derivative. If $F(M)$ is a matrix-valued derivative, then it’s directional derivative in the direction $\dot{M}$ is $$D_{\dot{M}}F(M) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}F(M+t\dot{M})$$ From here, it is easy to compute the partial derivatives.

Comment: @TedShifrin but we are talking about differentiating a matrix valued function with matrix variables with respect of ''one of its matrix arguments''

Comment: @Deane For a directional derivative it is ok, but I m asking about differenting with respect to variable which has the nature of being a matrix argument

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted. You want to think of it precisely Deane’s way. If you have $f(A,B)$, with $A\in M_{m\times n}$, then compute $Df_{(A,B)}(H)$ for an arbitrary $H\in M_{m\times n}$. Perhaps it would help to edit your post by adding a specific case of your question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

Comment: I deleted my answer, but in short, yeah, you need: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fréchet_derivative#Partial_Fréchet_derivatives

Comment: @user536450, it’s all the same. Differentiating with respect to a matrix is the same as setting $\dot{M}$ equal to each standard basis matrix (the matrix with a $1$ in the $i$th row and $j$th column and zeros everywhere else.